# wysiwyg is scrambled

Tags: editor, wysiwyg

I have a problem with the wordpress editor.
It keeps removing my enters and scrambling the content.
How can I solve this problem?

[image: Error in editor]

Comment: which version of wordpress you are using?

Comment: Last one (3.1.4). I always keep it up to date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using editor style for your wysiwyg.
Add `add_editor_style();` to your functions.php and then add a new file called `editor-style.css` to your main theme directory. Your editor style should reflect the basic css settings like your actual frontend content width, H1, H2, p etc tags styles, margins, image padding adn margins etc. Don't copy your default style.css, only the basic styling.

Here is an example of an editor-style.css file I used on my latest project (note html .mceContentBody):

```
html .mceContentBody {
width:690px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    color: #AC2327;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
}
h2 {
    color: #494949;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 0 15px;
}
ul li {
    color: #494949;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    list-style: disc inside url(includes/images/dot.gif);
    padding: 2px 0;
}
p {
    color: #494949;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 15px 0 5px;
}
p a {
    color: #CA1016;
    text-decoration: none;
}
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
img {
    border: 1px solid #E4E2E2;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 25px 25px;
}
hr {
    background-color: #D7D7D7;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #D7D7D7;
    float: left;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0 0 18px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Great. Exactly what I needed. Changing the how it is needed to resemble the front page.